# Есть ли ноутбуки лучше для машинного обучения?

Tags: машинное-обучение, железо, ноутбук

Требуется ноутбук преимущественно для задач машинного обучения и нейронных сетей, но также способный тянуть большое количество ресурсоемких рабочих приложений (blender, da vinci resolve и т.д.)
Ценовой диапазон 70-80к.
Нашел интересный вариант:
https://3dnews.ru/1077635/obzor-igrovogo-noutbuka-msi-katana-gf66-12ue868xru
Хотелось бы взять совет—насколько мой выбор хорош и есть ли более достойные альтернативы?

Comment: Ты спрашиваешь на сколько хорош смарт\ока\запорожец\жук для перевозки руды из карьера уточняя при этом цвет кузова и фирму брызговиков. Не надо так делать.

Comment: И да, ссылка битая.

Comment: Исправил ссылку

Comment: Нормальная машинка. Память надо будет доставить.

Answer (score 0):

Ноутбук хороший, но также есть
[Вот такой вариант](https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/5e25dddbd73ced20/156-noutbuk-msi-bravo-15-c7ve-037xru-cernyj/)
В нём 16гб оперативной памяти, с возможностью расширения до 64гб. Видеокарта rtx 4050, процессор amd ryzen 5 7535hs, 6 ядер 12 потоков.

Comment: Так вопрос писали в начале года, когда этой модели 2023 года ещё видимо не было )

Comment: Крайне интересный вариант, учитывая видеокарту 4050, но ноутбук действительно уже куплен)